# ASP.NET web deploy error code 255

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing a web deploy of MVC 5 to a web hosting site and i got the following error when viewing the page after deploying. I do now know how to resolve this issue as i do not have error message during local compilation nor have any problem running it locally

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code 255.
>
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv>
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library
>   /utf8output
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary

Comment: Reinstall .net framework and check on IIS the application pool identity ( version and permissions )

Comment: @Mate I do not have IIS install (can't find it in inetmgr). Does web deploy require IIS? The web deploy work previously

Comment: IIS must be installed on the destination server, check this : http://forums.asp.net/t/2032681.aspx?Can+anyone+tell+me+what+is+Compiler+Error+Message+The+compiler+failed+with+error+code+255+